# Using Angular ng-show/ng-hide with radio buttons

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm using `$scope.checked` to show/hide the "Top" text box, `name="numRows"` in my html.

However, even when I click on the 'top' radio button, `$scope.checked` always retains the value of `all' when I debug my controller code.

This simply plunker seems to work fine, http://plnkr.co/edit/6GoUZw7zkf8oqUmKg9hf?p=preview, but it won't work in my application.

In the plunker, there's a simple button whose click value will hit the controller event `$scope.showval` to show the value of either "top" or "all".

My HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group">                                
 <div class="row-fluid">
  <label class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label" for="numRows">Returned Rows</label>
  <!-- ALL ROWS RADIO -->
  <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1"> 
   <label class="radio-inline" for="radio-all">
    <input name="radios" id="radio-all" value="all" type="radio" ng-model="checked" ng-click="setTopRows('all')">All
   </label>                                         
  </div>
  <!-- TOP NUM OF ROWS RADIO -->
  <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1">                                    
   <label class="radio-inline" for="radio-top">
    <input name="radios" id="radio-top" value="top" type="radio" ng-model="checked" ng-click="setTopRows('top')">Top
   </label>
  </div>
  <!-- NUM OF ROWS TEXT BOX -->
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <input ng-show="checked == 'top'" ng-hide="checked == 'all'" type="text" class="form-control" name="numRows" ng-model="settings.numRowsReturned" placeholder="" >
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
   Click to show<input type="button" ng-click="showval(e)">
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

A snippet from my angular controller code :

The $scope.checked value is always 'all', even when I click on 'top' from the html.

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('rage')
       .controller('GadgetSettingsCtrl_NEW', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$modalInstance', gridSettings]);

    function gridSettings($rootScope, $scope, $modalInstance,) {

        var settings = this;

        $scope.checked = 'all';

        
        
        $scope.showval = function (e) {
            var test = $scope.checked;
        }
        
        $scope.setTopRows = function (numRows) {
            if (numRows === 'top') {
                $scope.checked = 'top';
            }
            else {
                $scope.checked = 'all';
            }
        }
        
        function checkOptions(){
            var top = '';
            if ($scope.checked === 'top') {
              top = (settings.numRowsReturned != undefined ? settings.numRowsReturned : '');
            }            
        }
      
  };   // end of gridSettings()    
})();
```

Can someone help me clear up why $scope.checked is NOT changing when I click on the radio buttons ?

thank you,
Bob

`****** UPDATE *********`

I've added a simple `ng-click="setTopRows('all')"` to force my scope variable to change. This works, but it seems like too much code to accomplish this.

---

Comment: In your `$scope.setTopRows` function, you are assigning value in if condition and not evaluating it. `if (numRows = 'top')`.

Comment: @Amit - right, good catch. That's the function I added in my Update note. Oddly enough, `if (numRows = 'top')` still ended up evaluating; however, I still don't understand why I need this $scope.setTopRows function .

Comment: You don't need the `setTopRows` function. Your code seems to be perfectly fine. I tried reproducing the scenario you are facing but failed to do so.

Are you sure your model value is not getting changed by some other part of your code ?

Comment: @Amit - No, I'm not sure. But I agree there must be something I'm missing. I'll debug again.